# Laravel: how to invalidate an update if an unknown field is passed

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a custom validator:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'sometimes|unique:stock.containers|max:255',
    ]);
```

I would like to throw an error if I do:

```
 PUT:localhost/my/model?description=foobar
```

Because I only want to accept `name` in this case. Then I would ensure that my `$validator->valid()` only contain accepted fields.

Here is my Controller:

```
class ContainerController extends Controller
{
    public function update($id, Request $request) {
        $container = Container::find($id);

        $rules = ['name' => 'max:255'];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);  //i'm not getting any
        }

        $container->update($validator->valid());
    }
}
```

And with the above request, I reach the `$container->update`. I would like to restrict the field to those mentioned in my rules.

Comment: What have you tried? I've noticed a lot of Laravel questions from you recently, which is fine, but you need to show what attempts you've made to solve your issue, and the error(s) you've run into.

Comment: For example, this one is probably as simple as looping the values in `$request`, comparing against a defined array of accepted variables, and throwing an error if you encounter something like `description` (or better stated, something that *isn't* `name`).

Comment: So *few* questions are *a lot of Laravel questions* according to you :) I modified my question to include what I tried.

Comment: @TimLewis, Yes I could easily solve this question is some low-level loops, but the purpose of a framework is to use already made features. Restricting a model update to a list of predefined fields looks something that anybody would use, so I am expecting an obvious feature available out of the box

Comment: I've seen 4 from you in the last 2 days. Comparatively against most users, that *is* a lot of questions :) But I didn't mean that in a negative way. Regardless, moving on. And yes, Laravel is a framework, but there is nothing wrong with using custom code in tandem. Is there an out-of-the-box feature that does this? I don't know; maybe? Was that your question? Also maybe, but not the way I interpreted it.

Comment: use `$request->except('description');` if you would not like to accept description field.

Comment: @VikashPathak Yes I could use `$request->only('name')`, but this will not throw an error if I attempt to update my model with an unknown field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `validate` method of the controller instead of making a new instance of Validator.

```
public function update($id, Request $request) {
    $valid = $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'max:255',
    ]);

    dd($valid);
}
```

So even if someone submits other params that are not included in the rules, it will not be included.

In our case, if you do the curl request as mentioned, `$valid` would return an empty array.

And then you could check if the array is empty or not:

```
if (empty($valid)) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

---

### Side Note

I noticed you are using `Container::find($id);` but you could also use the built-in model binding in your routes file:

```
Route::put('your-path/{container}', 'ContainerController@update');
```

Instead of

```
Route::put('your-path/{id}', 'ContainerController@update');
```

Which would then allow this in your controller:

```
public function update(Container $container, Request $request)
{
    // $container would be the Container instance already
}
```

---

### Update

If you still want to make a new Validator instance, you can do it like this:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


if ($validator->fails()) {
    // ...
}

if (! $valid = $validator->validated()) {
    // Nothing has been validated
}
```

Basically you should use `$validator->validated()` instead of `$validator->valid()` to retrieve the fields only from your rules.

Comment: Can I use `after` on this built-in validator?

Comment: @nowox What do you want to do with the `after`?

Comment: Thanks for showing me the built-in model binding, but does it work with a `resource` route?

Comment: This is a sensible approach to validation, but doesn't actually answer the question, which states  "I would like it to throw an error".

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is make a type of Request which filters out the parameters that you do not want, so you can pass it into your controller like: `private function myfunction(MyCustomRequest $request)`, so by the time it reaches your validator, the invalid parameters have already been removed.

In your `MyCustomRequest` you can have a list of valid parameters, like so:

```
 $validParameters = ["name"]; // add as many as you need
```

So you want to now check what is in the request, which you can see using `$request->all()`. You can iterate through your valid parameters and only pass back the request values that match your custom list.

```
 $requestData = $request->all();

 $goodRequestData = [];

 foreach ($validParameters as $validParameter) {
      if (array_key_exists($validParameter, $requestData) {
           $goodRequestData[] = $requestData[$validParameter];
      }
 }

 return $goodRequestData;
```

You can read more about custom requests in the Laravel docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: Yeah, I did not want to consider form requests because I feel the functionality is spread into many files. To update my database I need: 1. A model, 2. A view, 3. A controller, 4. Some Rules, 5. Some Requests. As my validations rules and requests are quite simple and specific to each of my route resources, I prefer to merge the API controllers, the rules and the requests together.

Comment: @nowox sometimes things we prefer are not for the best. Single responsibility principle exists for a reason. Extending `FormRequest` is a good way to encapsulate all the request related stuff (like validation, sanitizing/type casting etc) into separate class. Then your controller actions can reference those form requests in their parameters and framework will delegate all that routine to them. Then your controllers wouldn't have to worry about whether or not incoming data is valid - it's no longer their responsibility. Extending and utilizing `FormRequest` is exactly what you need.

Comment: This is a sensible approach to validation, but doesn't actually answer the question, which states "I would like it to throw an error".

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `->only()` method:

```php
class ContainerController extends Controller
{
    public function update($id, Request $request) {
        $container = Container::find($id);

        $rules = ['name' => 'max:255'];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);  //i'm not getting any
        }

        $container->update($request->only(['name']));
    }
}
```

From the docs:

> The only method returns all of the key / value pairs that you request; however, it will not return key / value pairs that are not present on the request.

Comment: In this case If I try to update my model with `?mispelled_field=42` I will net no error and I would spend ages to understand my mistake. I consider that if I try to update an not allowed field I should get a validation error. Is this wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, but seems to be unnecessary since you can just prevent these fields from being updated with the `only` method.

Comment: I agree with you, but if you want to be more robust, it is good to not ignore things that are not supported

Comment: So i think u can iterate through your `$request` keys with foreach or something else, and returns some message to the user if one or more not allowed fields are found.